# Use of some dependent variable as covariate

Tags: regression, paired-data, predictor, simultaneous-equation

The type of data I am interested has paired kind of responses.
Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_{n}$ denote first kind and $X_1, \ldots, X_{n}$ denote the second kind.

I have a matrix $Z$ for covariates and $X$ and $Y$ share some of the covariates. Let $A_y$ be the matrix indicating which covariates are used for Y and $A_x$ be the matrix indicating which covariates are used for X.

Now is it legitimate to fit $Y=A_yZ + BX$
and $X=A_xZ$ using both $Y$ and $X$ as responses? Or doe the use of $X$ in $Y$ restrict me in using $X$ as response?

Comment: I do not see $Y$ used as a covariate anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Algebraically, you can certainly regress $X$ on $Y$ and $Y$ on $X$. If you feel a subject-matter need to do so, you should however be concerned about reverse causality, which would invalidate a causal interpretation of your coefficient estimates.

Suppose you have the following equations in mind:

Effect of $X$ on $Y$: $Y_i =\beta_0 +\beta_1X_i + u_i$.

Effect of $Y$ on $X$: $X_i =\gamma_0 +\gamma_1Y_i + v_i$

A large value of $u_i$ implies a large value of $Y_i$, which implies a large value of $X_i$ (if $\gamma_1>0$). Hence, $Corr(X_i,u_i) \ne 0$.
Hence, $\hat\beta_1$ will be an inconsistent estimator of $\beta_1$. Basically, under such reverse causality, you need instrumental variables to identify the coefficients.

Comment: What I was wondering is is it legitimate to fit $Y=A_yZ + BX$ and $X=A_xZ$ in one model having both Y and X as response variables.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not clarify your question for me, as it, to me, just restates what you already wrote, so the best I can give is still my above answer (which has both $Y$ and $X$ as responses).